# best way to write series of objects to a .ser file using ObjectOutputStream and read them back

Tags: java, vectors, serialization

I create series of objects out of Student Class and store them in a vector. I write each object in to a .ser file once it created. Then I read them back. My code is working perfectly. What I want to know is, I do this in a correct optimized way or are there any easy and optimized ways to get this done?? And also how to replace or delete specific object in a .ser file without re-witting whole the file again.

Student Class

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>, Serializable{

    private String firstName = "";
    private int registrationNumber;
    private int coursework1;
    private int coursework2;
    private int finalExam;
    private double moduleMark;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public int getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }
    public void setRegistrationNumber(int registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }
    public int getCoursework1() {
        return coursework1;
    }
    public void setCoursework1(int coursework1) {
        this.coursework1 = coursework1;
    }
    public int getCoursework2() {
        return coursework2;
    }
    public void setCoursework2(int coursework2) {
        this.coursework2 = coursework2;
    }
    public int getFinalExam() {
        return finalExam;
    }
    public void setFinalExam(int finalExam) {
        this.finalExam = finalExam;
    }
    public double getModuleMark() {
        return moduleMark;
    }
    public void setModuleMark(double moduleMark) {
        this.moduleMark = moduleMark;
    }
    public int compareTo(Student s){
        if (this.moduleMark > s.moduleMark)
            return 1;
        else if (this.moduleMark == s.moduleMark)
            return 0;
        else 
            return -1;
    }
}
```

File writing part

```
public static void Write(Student mm){
        try
          {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("info.ser",true);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut));

            out.writeObject(mm);            
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Serialized data is saved in info.ser");
          }catch(IOException i)
          {
              //i.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
```

Reading part

```
public static int Read() {
        int count=0;
        try{
            vector = new Vector<Student>();
            FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("info.ser");
            ObjectInputStream save;
            try{
                for(;;){
                    save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
                    student = (Student) save.readObject();
                    vector.add(student);
                    count++;
                }
            }catch(EOFException e){
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            saveFile.close(); 

        }catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: your very last question is off topic, we won't tell you how to write a block of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why didn't you provide a constructor for `Student` class? Was that on purpose? However...

- Use [`serialVersionUID`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it).
- In Java it's recommended [not to use `Vector` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated), instead use `ArrayList`.
- `Write` method is serializing a `Student` individually. But as you stated you are writing a whole list of student into the `.ser` file. This will take many time for a list of 10,000 students.

  Because you are opening two streams for each student. So instead pass the whole list and serialize them after opening the stream only once.
- Do not close the stream in the `try` block. close them into `finally` block. Even better if you are using Java7 or higher use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block. It is easy to use and you don't have to manually close the stream.
- In `Read` method

  ```
          for(;;){
              save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
  ```

  you are creating new stream for every object thats not necessary instead do this

  ```
          save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
          for(;;){
  ```
- Onwards Java7 there is [`multiple catch statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). Give it a *try*(pun intended).
- In Java we use [mixed-case convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) for naming a method. So `Write` and `Read` would be `write` and `read`.

Comment: I'm new to java and means a lot ur quick reply. learnt a lot. Thanks for ur time :)